# How do you keep one letter a color and the rest another color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

tl;dr output all is in blue for tic tac toe, only want x as blue and o as red

In class we're trying to make a tic tac toe game and currently we're trying to modify the code in such a way that only X is blue and O is red however when we import colorama it colors all of the output. I am aware that all of the text will print in blue. So essentially it should look like: [image] 
I've also provided the code for the game.

```
import random
import colorama 
from colorama import Fore, Style
print(Fore.BLUE + "Hello World")
player_1_pick = ""
player_2_pick = ""

if (player_1_pick == "" or player_2_pick == ""):
  if (player_1_pick == ""):
    player_1_pick = "Player 1"
  if (player_2_pick == ""):
    player_2_pick = "Player 2"
else:
  pass

board = ["_"] * 9

def print_board():
  print(board[0] + '|' + board[1] + '|' + board[2])
  print(board[3] + '|' + board[4] + '|' + board[5])
  print(board[6] + '|' + board[7] + '|' + board[8])

print_board()
if (random.randint(1,2) == 1):
  player_1_pick = input(player_1_pick + ", choose X or O: ").upper()
  if (player_1_pick == "X"):
    player_2_pick = "O"



while True:
  x = input('Pick a number from 0-8')
  x = int(x)
  board[x] = 'X'
  print_board()
```

Then we decided to open another tab of python (we're using repl.it) to try and fix the problem in an isolated environment, in which we came up with:

```
import random
import colorama 
from colorama import Fore, Style
def getPieceLabel(piece):
  if (piece == 1):
    return "|" + color.PURPLE + color.BOLD + "X" + color.END + "|"
  elif (piece == 2 ):
    return "|" + color.BLUE + color.BOLD + "O"
    + "|" 
  else:
    return color.BOLD + "|_|" + color.END 

board = ["_"] * 9

def print_board():
  print(board[0] + '|' + board[1] + '|' + board[2])
  print(board[3] + '|' + board[4] + '|' + board[5])
  print(board[6] + '|' + board[7] + '|' + board[8])
  print(Style.RESET_ALL)

while True:
  x = input('Pick a number from 0-8')
  x = int(x)
  board[x] = 'X'
  print_board()
```

We need some help figuring this out/what the problem is.

Comment: In your first code, it all prints in blue cause in your 4th line you set the font colour as blue. So all your text will now print in blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that works for printing different color for different items (tested on repl.it too!).

```py
import random
import colorama 
from colorama import Fore, Style

print(Fore.BLUE + "Tic Tac Toe")
Style.RESET_ALL

player_1_pick = ""
player_2_pick = ""

if (player_1_pick == "" or player_2_pick == ""):
  if (player_1_pick == ""):
    player_1_pick = "Player 1"
  if (player_2_pick == ""):
    player_2_pick = "Player 2"
else:
  pass

board = ["_"] * 9

def print_board():
  for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
      if (board[i*3 + j] == 'X'):
        print(Fore.BLUE + board[i*3 + j], end = '')
      elif (board[i*3 + j] == 'O'):
        print(Fore.RED + board[i*3 + j], end = '')
      else:
        print(board[i*3 + j], end = '')

      print(Style.RESET_ALL, end = '')

      if j != 2:
        print('|', end = '')

    print() # new line

print_board()

if (random.randint(1,2) == 1):
  player_1_pick = input(player_1_pick + ", choose X or O: ").upper()
  if (player_1_pick == "X"):
    player_2_pick = "O"

while True:
  x = input('Pick a number from 0-8: ')
  x = int(x)
  board[x] = 'X'
  print_board()
```

**Why?** When you use `Back.RED` or `Fore.RED`, it just changes the global output color (and not just that particular `print()` statement). That means you must change color for every to-be-printed item if you want them in different colors. That's what I did under `print_board()`.

Since you're printing a 3x3 matrix (or 2D array) along with borders between the elements or items, I had to make use of two loops to print each of them in different colors (as required).

**Note:** The program works, but I think there is some missing logic since the game only works for 1st player; there is no second player (or even a system player). It's out of the scope for this answer.